# Powershell Global Hotkeys (Block existing)

Tags: powershell, user32

I am trying to write a simple hotkey app that writes out text we use frequently to save my team time.  I have it working but am struggling to find a key combination that doesn't already do something in Microsoft Office.  Therefore I was hoping to modify the script to block those hotkeys and use my own instead.  Problem is I barely understand the code I am using as is.  Here is the code piece, I am hoping someone smarter than I will have some luck.

Side Note, cannot use one of the many applications that already does this nicely for me.  Long story.

Bonus Question - Anyone have a faster way to paste in a bunch of text to the foreground application.  Sendkey is slower than I'd like.  I had a version where I put the text into the clipboard and pasted it, but the team needs their clipboard unaltered.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null
while ($true) {
    try
    {
        $ImportDll = [User32]
    }
    catch
    {
        $DynAssembly = New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName('Win32Lib')
        $AssemblyBuilder = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, [Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run)
        $ModuleBuilder = $AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule('Win32Lib', $False)
        $TypeBuilder = $ModuleBuilder.DefineType('User32', 'Public, Class')

        $DllImportConstructor = [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetConstructor(@([String]))
        $FieldArray = [Reflection.FieldInfo[]] @(
            [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('EntryPoint'),
            [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('ExactSpelling'),
            [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('SetLastError'),
            [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('PreserveSig'),
            [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('CallingConvention'),
            [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('CharSet')
        )

        $PInvokeMethod = $TypeBuilder.DefineMethod('GetAsyncKeyState', 'Public, Static', [Int16], [Type[]] @([Windows.Forms.Keys]))
        $FieldValueArray = [Object[]] @(
            'GetAsyncKeyState',
            $True,
            $False,
            $True,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention]::Winapi,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet]::Auto
        )
        $CustomAttribute = New-Object Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder($DllImportConstructor, @('user32.dll'), $FieldArray, $FieldValueArray)
        $PInvokeMethod.SetCustomAttribute($CustomAttribute)

        $PInvokeMethod = $TypeBuilder.DefineMethod('GetKeyboardState', 'Public, Static', [Int32], [Type[]] @([Byte[]]))
        $FieldValueArray = [Object[]] @(
            'GetKeyboardState',
            $True,
            $False,
            $True,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention]::Winapi,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet]::Auto
        )
        $CustomAttribute = New-Object Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder($DllImportConstructor, @('user32.dll'), $FieldArray, $FieldValueArray)
        $PInvokeMethod.SetCustomAttribute($CustomAttribute)

        $PInvokeMethod = $TypeBuilder.DefineMethod('MapVirtualKey', 'Public, Static', [Int32], [Type[]] @([Int32], [Int32]))
        $FieldValueArray = [Object[]] @(
            'MapVirtualKey',
            $False,
            $False,
            $True,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention]::Winapi,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet]::Auto
        )
        $CustomAttribute = New-Object Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder($DllImportConstructor, @('user32.dll'), $FieldArray, $FieldValueArray)
        $PInvokeMethod.SetCustomAttribute($CustomAttribute)

        $PInvokeMethod = $TypeBuilder.DefineMethod('ToUnicode', 'Public, Static', [Int32],
            [Type[]] @([UInt32], [UInt32], [Byte[]], [Text.StringBuilder], [Int32], [UInt32]))
        $FieldValueArray = [Object[]] @(
            'ToUnicode',
            $False,
            $False,
            $True,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention]::Winapi,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet]::Auto
        )
        $CustomAttribute = New-Object Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder($DllImportConstructor, @('user32.dll'), $FieldArray, $FieldValueArray)
        $PInvokeMethod.SetCustomAttribute($CustomAttribute)

        $PInvokeMethod = $TypeBuilder.DefineMethod('GetForegroundWindow', 'Public, Static', [IntPtr], [Type[]] @())
        $FieldValueArray = [Object[]] @(
            'GetForegroundWindow',
            $True,
            $False,
            $True,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention]::Winapi,
            [Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet]::Auto
        )
        $CustomAttribute = New-Object Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder($DllImportConstructor, @('user32.dll'), $FieldArray, $FieldValueArray)
        $PInvokeMethod.SetCustomAttribute($CustomAttribute)

        $ImportDll = $TypeBuilder.CreateType()
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 25

    try
    {

        #loop through typeable characters to see which is pressed
        for ($TypeableChar = 1; $TypeableChar -le 254; $TypeableChar++)
        {
            $VirtualKey = $TypeableChar
            $KeyResult = $ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState($VirtualKey)
            #if the key is pressed
            if (($KeyResult -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000)
            {

                #check for keys not mapped by virtual keyboard
                $LeftShift    = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::LShiftKey) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $RightShift   = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::RShiftKey) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$LeftCtrl     = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::LControlKey) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$RightCtrl    = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::RControlKey) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $LeftAlt      = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::LMenu) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $RightAlt     = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::RMenu) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$TabKey       = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Tab) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$SpaceBar     = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Space) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$DeleteKey    = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Delete) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$BackSpaceKey = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Back) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$LeftArrow    = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Left) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$RightArrow   = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Right) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$UpArrow      = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Up) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$DownArrow    = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Down) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $one         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D1) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $two         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D2) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $three         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D3) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $four         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D4) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $five         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D5) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $six         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D6) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $seven         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D7) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $eight         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D8) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $nine         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D9) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                $zero         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::D0) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000
                #$escape         = ($ImportDll::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::Escape) -band 0x8000) -eq 0x8000

                #check for capslock
                #$caps = ([Console]::CapsLock)

                if (($LeftAlt -or $RightAlt) -and ($LeftShift -or $RightShift))  {
                    if ($one) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[1])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($two) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[2])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($three) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[3])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($four) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[4])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($five) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[5])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($six) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[6])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($seven) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[7])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($eight) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[8])
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($nine) {
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[9])                           
                        return
                    }
                    elseif ($zero) {  
                        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($savedData[0])                         
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question exactly? Why reinvent the wheel when there is an existing [hotkey app](http://www.autohotkey.com/) you can use?

Comment: its a pain...I have to use a home grown solution because the company I work for is stupidly strict about applications.  it would cost way too much to have them certify an existing app.  I just need to modify the above code so that the identified hotkey combinations don't make it back to windows, executes my sendkey but doesn't perform whatever action widnows already has assigned to that combo.

Comment: Cost is relative. If you need it, it will probably cost less to certify an open source and freely available application than the man-hours to try to write one in-house when you don't have programming experience.

Comment: While I agree with you this is not up for debate.  I have explained that I require a home grown solution.  I don't wish to further discuss the budget the company I work for has.  If you too lack the experience to help me perhaps someone else can.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're on your own then...good luck...